# How should the human body be arranged, adapted to the lethal level of radiation?

Tags: biology, creature-design, humans, hard-science

A lethal dose is considered to be 6 Sievert and above, but absolutely lethal exposure to a dose of over 10 Sievert. The main reason for cell death under extreme environmental influences (in our case, radiation) is DNA destruction.

So, with a single uniform irradiation of the whole body and the failure to provide specialized medical care, death as a result of acute radiation sickness occurs in 50% of cases:

At a dose of the order of 3-5 Sievert due to damage to the bone marrow within 30-60 days;

10 ± 5 Sievert due to damage to the gastrointestinal tract and lungs within 10-20 days;

> 15 Sievert due to damage to the nervous system within 1-5 days.

So we return to the essence of my question: how should the body be arranged (most likely, it will concern a change in the structure or the process of cell division) so that my genetically engineered people can be exposed to radiation of 80-120 Sievert without any harm to health  what is fatal to humans?

Comment: Instead of copy-pasting, please do as the text says: flag your post for moderator attention and ask the post notice to be added.

Comment: If you could (temporarily) convince the body to stop cells from reproducing, then the DNA damage becomes very much less significant. The next threshold where cells are *directly* killed by the radiation requires dosages that are tens to hundreds of times higher. Of course, one cannot survive very long with al cell division on hold. Blood cells need to be replaced, healing of almost any sort requires cell division, etc. But preventing cells with malfunctioning DNA from dividing will, in the very short term, remove a great many of the symptoms of radiation damage.

Comment: P.S. If you insist on the "Hard Science" tag, then please rephrase your question to refer to Sievert, not Gray. You are dealing with purely biological effects, and Sievert is the appropriate measurement. Any answer to your question using Gray would be disqualified, under this tag.

Answer (score 5):

**Radical reorganization of the body towards staged growth or ecdysis/molting**

This is going to be a little bit of a non-answer, but bear with me because it's going to highlight exactly what you need to address when designing a radiation-resistant human.

Cockroaches, scorpions, and other arthropods are much more resistant to radiation than vertebrates and most other organisms are. The reason for this has to do with the fact that arthropods grow in stages by molting, rather than perpetually growing at a slow rate over the animal's lifespan the way vertebrates do. Cellular DNA is much more susceptible to mutation and radiation damage when cells are dividing and the DNA is exposed. By restricting cellular division to a relatively brief period of molting rather than a prolonged period of growth, arthropods only have to worry about a relatively brief window where their bodies are especially vulnerable to radiation damage.

However, doing this in humans would require a complete reorganization of our body. Most of the body is designed to grow slowly in stages, this ranges from our bones to our skin and muscles. If you rearranged the human body to grow like an insect it would also stop us from healing from injuries except when molting, so any damage to skin or muscle wouldn't heal over time unless you molted. Which is a lot worse for an animal that has its skeleton on the inside rather than the outside.

Answer (score 4):

#### Morbid obesity, specifically large enough that theres 42cm of water surrounding everything valuable.

Your people are obese giants, but where normal humans have fat cells, yours have water.

7cm of water will [halve the radiation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1336/what-thickness-depth-of-water-would-be-required-to-provide-radiation-shielding-i#:%7E:text=Well%2C%20according%20to%20a%20report,energy%20levels%2C%20mainly%20heat), and each additional 7cm will halve again. This will lower the absorbed radiation into the bone marrow, lungs, and gastrointestinal system by a factor of 64.

Theyll struggle to walk (they may need those scooter things), theyll be covered in melanoma scars from skin cancers, and they might not be able to get through doorways, but theyll survive the radiation.

Answer (score 3):

**Block DNA damage sensors.  Damaged cells will not kill themselves because they will not know they are damaged.**

This is a riff on @user2352714 (rolls off the fingers, that moniker does) about cell reproduction.

Why does the bone marrow and gut suffer from radiation, but not the muscles?  Muscles have DNA.  Maybe because muscle cells are not dividing.  But mature white cells and lymphocytes they are mature and terminally differentiated and they are not dividing but they still all die.   It is not so much that they wear out but that enough DNA damage could turn such a cell into cancer.

Cells contain sensors for DNA damage.  Cells that are exposed to the environment (mucosa, epithelia) divide a lot because they are the most prone to DNA damage.   The white cells contain oxidative weaponry that makes them prone to damage also.  Plus white cells are intrinsically dangerous and you need to be able to recycle them when their work is done.
That is one way cytotoxic chemotherapy and radiation work to treat cancer.  These things induce more DNA damage and push an already damaged cell further to the point where the cell's DNA damage sensors finally kick in and the cell commits suicide - apoptosis.

There are some types of cancers that are unaffected by DNA damaging agents.  There are healthy cells that are unaffected like muscle, fat, brain, blood vessel, cartilage etc.  These cells do not have the suicide pathways triggered by DNA damage sensors.

The DNA damage sensors are looking for bits of damaged DNA.  They are basically chemical sensors and so you could drug them and block their operation.  Or if this is a genetic engineering question you could hack them and make them less sensitive, or inducible on demand only by a drug.

The result - badly damaged cells do not commit apoptosis and instead soldier on.   The DNA damage in these cells may result in their gradually being unable to do their jobs over time.  The thyroid gland is a good example - if it gets hit by radiation used to treat throat cancer, the thyroid does not die but is less and less able to produce thyroid hormone as time goes by.  A proportion of damaged cells will have DNA damage that turns on growth pathways and these will become cancers.  Cancer takes a while to kill and so your radiation resistant soldiers will go along with multiple cancers of different kinds.

The soldiers will need to stay on that DNA damage sensor suppressing drug because if those pathways remain intact, when they wake up they will see all the damage and all those damaged cells will undergo apoptosis and die, unless that pathway has been damaged by the radiation too.

Comment: "badly damaged cells do not commit apoptosis and instead soldier on" - this will be only kicking the can down the road and lead to quick and massive cancers.

Comment: This does lead to massive cancers down the road. And it does expose the danger of rapid death when the mechanism get switched on again. But it *does* keep the body alive despite receiving many-times-lethal radiation exposure. Allowing, for example, a soldier to soldier on. Or an accident victim to be moved to the radiation intensive care, *before* the nasty symptoms start. Or to allow piecemeal reactivation of cell repair/death mechanisms, so the damage is spread over time, allowing treatment.

Comment: In short, moderately high radiation does not kill a human. It's the body's own overreaction to the radiation damage that kills itself.

Comment: Still, OP's question is "without any harm to health what is fatal to humans". We are trading short-term damage to long-term damage - without any specific plans to mitigate that damage.

Comment: @Alexander - you are right but I thought planning for long term for these folks was out of scope; OP mentioned acute radiation sickness and a giant lethal dose so the aim is to make that less lethal.  PCMan lays out several ways to reduce long term mortality for an entity numb to DNA damage,.  I like the piecemeal reactivation idea the best but if you are using a drug for the whole organism that is also the trickiest.